# How do you deploy onto Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I was wondering how do you deploy a FastAPI app on to Heroku as my current procfile configuration doesn't work.

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:app
api: uvicorn main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-5000}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to run `gunicorn` _and_ `uvicorn`?

Comment: @Chris I'm using gunicorn and uvicorn because the application has a frontend and a backend, gunicorn is used to run the frontend

Comment: That's not how it works. You get _one_ port, which means _one_ service. Usually, you'd build your front-end code during the build process and serve it up as static files.